# How does QML handle app quitting from menu bar on Mac?

Tags: qt, qml

I have an application which runs both on Windows and Mac.
The application is written in QML.
The most outer component in my QML code is an `ApplicationWindow`.
The `ApplicationWindow` component's API has a property called `menuBar`.
Here is a dummy example, which reproduces this with a `MenuBar` and a quitting `Action`:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: _applicationWindow

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.info("ApplicationWindow completed.")
    }

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: "File"

            MenuItem {
                action: Action {
                    id: _myQuttingAction

                    text: "Quit MyApp"
                    shortcut: "Ctrl+Q"

                    onTriggered: {
                        // deinit...
                        console.info("I got called!")
                        Qt.quit()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application on Mac the following top menu bar titles appear:

`Apple Icon menu | MyApp | File`

If I drop down the "File" menu this is what I get:
[image: MyApp's "File" menu drop down]

As you can see the drop down is empty. Actually it isn't empty because it is pressable and if I press it, it does quit my application with all deinit calls in the action's `onTriggered` event.

If I drop down the "MyApp" menu, at the bottom I see "Quit MyApp" with the shortcut `Cmd+Q`. If I press this, this quits my application as well, but without calling my action's `onTriggered` event, thus my real application crashes on quit.

Unfortunately pressing `Cmd+Q` also calls the quit from the "MyApp" not my specified action.

On Windows I don't have this problem at all and the "Quit MyApp" appears under the "File" menu and does what I expect it to do.

I tried to google this problem and read the documentation without luck yet. Anybody know what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

It is not realistic to expect that Qt quitting will somehow magically use your particular menu action, which is completely optional and arbitrary.

It is possible that it is not your shortcut that's invoking the action, but something built in that is platform specific, like how Alt+F4 works on windoze for example.

Since you are using `ApplicationWindow` you can implement a custom exit handler, which will be used regardless how you quit the application:

```
  onClosing: {
    // do your stuff
    close.accepted = true // exits, if set to false the quit request will be ignored
  }
```

Update: Since you say the above code doesn't work as expected, the quitting must be happening at an even lower level that doesn't even notify qtquick, which could also explain the crashing. I don't currently have a macos machine to look into it, however there is decent chance you could get it to quit property by hooking a handler to the `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()` signal.

Comment: Hi @dtech, setting `close.accepted = false` still makes my app quit, even trying with my dummy example above.

Comment: Also why doesn't the string "Quit MyApp" appear under the "File" menu drop down?

Comment: @Silex see the update, other than that I am currently out of ideas, someone else might be able to help.

Comment: Ah, this `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()` sounds like a good idea. Let me try!

Comment: I think I found the source of my problem: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33235 :/

Comment: Typical Qt... a 4 year old important bug still unresolved.